# how to shift column in java xssf poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How to copy an existing column data and formatting into next column in Apache POI and shift the next column to right.

I tried this.
Let say my code is this...

```
XSSFCell oldCell = worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(1);
XSSFCell newCell =  worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(2);

if(styleMap != null) {   
        if(oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()){   
            newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());   
        } else{   
            int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();   
            XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);   
            if(newCellStyle == null){   
                newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();   
                newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());   
                styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);   
            }   
            newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);   
        }   

    }
```

I able to copy value from old cell to new cell but it doesn't shift the existing column to right.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What actually happened? Did the values from the first column appear in the second column?  Your code above never deleted the first column cell?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is how to shift column after populating data from above code.  --Yes, it appears but it overwrite the data of the next cell.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't worked with POI in several years, but if I remember correctly you must iterate over all the cells in a row and update the column number in each `Cell` to be what you want. There's no magic "insert column" method.  Remember to do this from right to left to avoid completely trashing the worksheet :-)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot believe that it is not in the API.

You can use those 2 handy functions. I will try to make PR to the Apache POI later on.

```
void shiftColumns(Row row, int startingIndex, int shiftCount) {
    for (int i = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells()-1;i>=startingIndex;i--){
        Cell oldCell = row.getCell(i);
        Cell newCell = row.createCell(i + shiftCount, oldCell.getCellTypeEnum());
        cloneCellValue(oldCell,newCell);
    }
}

void cloneCellValue(Cell oldCell, Cell newCell) { //TODO test it
    switch (oldCell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
        case STRING:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case NUMERIC:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case BOOLEAN:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case FORMULA:
            newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
            break;
        case ERROR:
            newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
        case BLANK:
        case _NONE:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recently in release 4.1.1 Apache POI given an API to shift columns but it is in beta and not working as expected.

Comment: good idea, very helpful, after add a remove cell fuction, work on my demand

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [link]
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#shiftColumns-int-int-int-

Imagining Sheet is already created,
simply use this `worksheet.shiftColumns(int startcol, int lastcol, int cols_to_be_moved);`

```
worksheet.shiftColumns(0,13,1)
```

Note :

- index starts from 0.
- lastcol has to be the last column of your sheet in above case last col is 13
- cols_to_be_moved will determine number of cols to shift, negative number will shift left